# How to use azure sql db managed identity authentication for local development and on external tomcat (for deployment)?

Tags: sql-server, azure, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application connected to azure sql db using sql authentication (user/pass). It's working fine on local development and when the .war is deployed to external tomcat because the application is to be used on a linux environment.

I'm trying to use managed identity for authentication and came upon this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spring-cloud/connect-managed-identity-to-azure-sql).

I tried to implement it on my spring boot application but I'm getting this error:
"Windows logins are not supported in this version of sql server."

Also can this be used if I am not using azure cloud? As I mentioned earlier the application is being deployed in a linux server on tomcat.

Comment: Basically Managed Identities only work if you are running in Azure, they are a feature of Azure VMs, App Service etc.

Comment: I see, I'll stick to what I have for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, MSI(managed identity) just works in the [azure services that support MSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/services-support-managed-identities)(need enable MSI first), when using MSI to auth, it essentially makes an API call to the [azure instance metadata endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-use-vm-token#get-a-token-using-http) to get the access token, then use the token to auth, it is just available in the MSI-supported service. So in conclusion, you could not use this feature if you are not using azure cloud.